# Hand Made Blog Code View/display?

Tags: php, view, xhtml, blogs

I have hand coded my blog, no wordpress or anything, and I am trying to make a feature that would allow me to write code in my blog and display it like: `<div>Like This</div>`
I am probably thinking about it way to much, it might be simpler than I think. What I was trying to do was just find `<code></code>` tags in the blog post and replace all the `<` with `$lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, etc. that were found inside the `<code></code>` tags. But I could think of a way where it would do it for multiple `<code></code>` tags.

Then at the very end of the code I would replace `<code></code>` with `<div class="code"></div>`

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$html="<code>this is the first code snippet</code><p>This is a normal paragraph</p><code>this is the second code snippet</code>";
preg_match_all("'<code>(.*?)</code>'si", $html, $match);
if ($match) {
    foreach ($match[1] as $snippet) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($snippet, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo "\n";           
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, can you explain the preg_match_all tester? 
What does the `(.*?)' and the `si` do? Is `$match` just the Boolean catcher?

Comment: - http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php
 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for replacing `<code></code>` with `<div class="code"></div>` and [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode all html tags so it can be viewed as source code .

Comment: I understand that, however, if I do that ALL html tags will be viewed as source code. I just want code inside of the `<code>` tags to be source code.

Comment: @krewe you can do a htmlentities to all the text first (you'll know you don't have any script injection) and replace the encoded <code></code> with div tags u wanted . Those 2 functions will do your job, youll have to choose the way you want to use them.